# How to set default URL Path in Tomcat 6

Tags: mod-proxy, tomcat

I have installed Tomcat 6 and Jenkins. I can connect to it via `http://localhost/jenkins`, but i want to access it directly via `http://localhost`. How can I archive this?
My complete setup includes a host computer with Apache2 installed and it routes several subdomains to virtual machines. So if it is easier to do it in Apache, I could do it too, but I would prefer the first solution.

I am completely new to the Java and Tomcat world, so this might be pretty easy, but I didn't got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use URL rewriting. These two posts from stackoverflow: [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563799/how-to-rewrite-url-in-tomcat-6), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950497/is-there-a-url-rewriting-engine-for-tomcat-java) suggest to use URLrewriteFilter.

Any easier option may be to run your webapp as ROOT webapp in tomcat. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638787/default-web-app-in-tomcat) on how to do so.

Comment: Sorry, im to stupid to get it...it says something about context dir and web-inf dir in the install guide. I have never heard it. :(

Comment: Isn't it possible to just tell tomcat to start jenkins if / is called? Or can i configure jenkins to start on / instead of /jenkins? The standalone Jenkins was working with no /jenkins added, after some configuration.

Comment: @Abenil: Edited the answer.